# Are there any beginner/intermediate level Physics textbooks with Python?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I have been working on learning Python for about 6 months now. I have also taken 2 years of undergraduate Physics. I have been trying to find a beginner to intermediate level Physics textbook which also incorporates Python. I'm hoping to work on my programming skills while also brushing up some old concepts from undergrad - I also think it would be enjoyable to revisit old material with new skills.

Any thoughts on some literature that blends both beginner/intermediate level Physics and Python?

Comment: Hi John! Which subjects are you interested in studying?

Comment: I'd like to revisit Newtonian mechanics and vectors to start, but also interested in thermodynamics. Generally looking for any literature that blends Physics I or II with Python

Comment: In general any computational physics book will cover problems with these subjects. You can try this [text](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/cp/chapters/programming.pdf), or get [this](https://www.amazon.com/Computational-Physics-Mark-Newman/dp/1480145513/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1480348231&sr=1-1&keywords=computational+physics) book. My advise is: if you're interested in this, try to contact a research group at your school, and start working on problem that allows you to do computational physics